# grid `row-end-[x]` property in tailwind/css doesn't seem to work

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css

Apologies if this is obvious, but it's driving me mad. `row-end-[x]` doesn't seem to work as I expect. I think this simple demo replicates my problem: Why doesn't the image actually *end* on row 6?

[image]

Appreciate any help!

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) using the `<>` icon.  See [**How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex) **IMAGES OF CODE ARE NOT A SUITABLE REPLACEMENT**

Comment: **THANKS PAULIE, APPRECIATE IT**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is that `row-end-[x]` *is* working, by default the element overflows the grid area downwards so it looks like it isn't adhering to that property. To fix it I had to apply `self-end` to the element so it overflows upwards - it will then end on the given row